# Semantic-ui, checkbox sem ação no form

Tags: css, html5, checkbox, semantic-ui

Criei um formulário usando o Semantic-Ui, mas não consigo habilitas os checkbox, será que preciso de algum javascript específico para esses elementos?

[image: Exemplo do formulário]

```
<table class="ui table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="four wide column">Acesso</th>
        <th class="twoelve wide column">Permissão</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="ui segment"><div class="field"><div class="ui toggle checkbox">
            <input name="access_user" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox"><label>Usuários</label></div></div></div>        
        </td>
        <td><div class="ui segment"><div class="inline field"><div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="perm_user"><label for="perm_user">Só leitura</label>
            <input type="radio" name="perm_user"><label for="perm_user">Leitura & Gravação</label>
            <input type="radio" name="perm_user"><label for="perm_user">Controle Total</label></div></div></div>    
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="ui segment"><div class="field"><div class="ui checkbox">
        <input name="access_user" tabindex="0" class="hidden" type="checkbox"><label>Cupom</label></div></div></div>        
    </td>
        <td><div class="ui segment"><div class="inline fields"><div class="field"><div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="perm_cupom"><label for="perm_cupom">Só leitura</label>
            <input type="radio" name="perm_cupom"><label for="perm_cupom">Leitura & Gravação</label>
            <input type="radio" name="perm_cupom"><label for="perm_cupom">Controle Total</label></div></div></div></div>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>3 People</th>
        <th>2 Approved</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu HTML não está estruturado de acordo com as especificações da biblioteca. Você não pode colocar múltiplos elementos `radio` dentro de uma mesma `div.ui.radio.checkbox`. Esta `div` deve conter apenas um campo do formulário. Veja um exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui piled segment">
  <h4 class="ui header">Permissão</h4>
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="perm_user" id="perm_user_read_only">
    <label for="perm_user_read_only">Só leitura</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="perm_user" id="perm_user_read_write">
    <label for="perm_user_read_write">Leitura e Escrita</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui radio checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="perm_user" id="perm_user_all">
    <label for="perm_user_all">Controle Total</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alguns elementos do seu formulário inclusive possuem a classe `.hidden` que parece interferir no funcionamento do mesmo. Se o comportamento não está como o esperado, talvez seja interessante rever esta classe.